# Java rest post/put

Tags: java, rest, post

Im trying to create a simple java rest service. When I try to use post method I get the error. I am using postman application to interact with my postgresql db. What should I do and change to make it work ?

Here is my post query at postman.

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Alexander",
    "age": 23,
    "country": "Ukraine",
    "city": "Kyiv"
}
```

**My entity class**

```
@Entity
public class Us implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @Column(name="Name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "Age")
    private int age;
    @Column(name = "Country")
    private String country;
    @Column(name = "City")
    private String city;
    .....
    Getters and Setters
    .....
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Us user = (Us) o;
        return id == user.id &&
                age == user.age &&
                Objects.equals(name, user.name) &&
                Objects.equals(country, user.country) &&
                Objects.equals(city, user.city);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(id, name, age, country, city);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", country='" + country + '\'' +
                ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**My registrator class**

```
@Stateless
public class UsRegistrator {

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public Us createUs(long id, int age, String city, String country, String name){
        Us us = new Us();
        us.setId(id);
        us.setAge(age);
        us.setCity(city);
        us.setCountry(country);
        us.setName(name);
        entityManager.merge(us);
        logger.info("Created user object " + us);
        return us;
    }
}
```

**My Rest service**

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("/user")
public class UsREST {
    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    @Inject
    private UsRepository userRepository;

    @Inject
    private UsRegistrator userRegistrator;

    @POST
    @Path("/create")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Us createUser(@QueryParam("id") long id,
                               @QueryParam("age") int age,
                               @QueryParam("city") String city,
                               @QueryParam("country") String country,
                               @QueryParam("name") String name){
        return userRegistrator.createUs(id,age,city,country,name);
    }
}
```

Error logs:

> 01:18:26,477 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-3) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502
>      01:18:26,477 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-3) ERROR: null value in column "city" violates not-null constraint
>        Подробности: Failing row contains (15, 0, null, null, null).
>      01:18:26,569 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] (default task-3) HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
>      01:18:26,610 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (default task-3) ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffffc0a8011a:775c2d9d:5b21962e:28, org.jboss.as.txn.service.internal.tsr.JCAOrderedLastSynchronizationList@6ceb5f33 >: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
>         at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
>         at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
>         at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
>         at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(EntityManagerImpl.java:235)
>         at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2967)
>         at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
>         at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:316)
>         at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:47)
>         at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:37)
>      Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
>         at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
>         at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
>         at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2897)
>         at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3397)
>         at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
>         at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
>         at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
>         at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
>         at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465)
>         at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963)
>         ... 114 more
>      Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "city" violates not-null constraint
>        Подробности: Failing row contains (15, 0, null, null, null).
>         at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2412)
>         at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2125)
>         at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:297)
>         at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
>         at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
>         at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:169)
>         at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:136)
>         at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:537)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
>         ... 125 more
>
> 01:18:26,637 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-3) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component UsRegistrator for method public webapprest.entity.Us webapprest

Comment: Hint: "ERROR: null value in column "city" violates not-null constraint"

Comment: But i input all fields in my post query in postman.

Comment: you are sending the input as JSON in the POST body. Right?

Comment: try debugging the code, is `city` and the other variables getting correctly populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sending input in URL or body ?

First things first why you have your object as (15, 0, null, null, null) is because

```
-15-id is auto generated,
-0-age because `private int age;` you defined age as primitive int so it takes default
    value if you don't pass anything so 0
-as other others are defined string so they are null if not passed any value
```

But looking at the request it seems like you are sending json object in body
If you are sending request as JSON body then you should Object input and cast it to your entity 
so your method should be

```
@POST
@Path("/create")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Us createUser(JsonObject jsonObject){
    int age=jsonObject.get("age");

    int id=jsonObject.get("id");
    String city=jsonObject.get("city");
    String country=jsonObject.get("country");
    String name=jsonObject.get("name");
    return userRegistrator.createUs(id,age,city,country,name);
}
```